# Broken printing

Tags: bug, printing

I fail to print out any question with answers on any SE site without considerable trouble.

Simply printing it out results in only the first page (paper page, not WWW page) being printed. For reasons beyond my comprehension the rest is truncated.

More manual approach to printing (copy&pasting to an office suite document) is possible, but is a PITA.

Any chance for this to be fixed? I must admit being able to print out some questions is pretty important for me for personal reasons.

Happens at least on the recent version of firefox and has been happening for quite a long time now. I don't have time to test other browsers atm, but will test MSEdge in the evening.

Comment: I see no problem when I hit Print. What do you get?